# Using _ to refer to variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Are there any dangers associated with using "_" instead of "self." for variables? I'm so used to it just because it saves some space. In blocks I get a warning so I use "self." instead. Should I stop? I was also used to declaring every variable as "nonatomic" but I since have stopped.

Comment: "*I was also used to declaring every variable as "nonatomic" but I since have stopped.*" Why have you "*stopped*", exactly? If you want to declare your variables as `nonatomic`, why not do so...?

Comment: Because they are not "thread safe" and it's not the default method. I still haven't understood what "thread safe" means but I'm not taking any chances...